# I got an email from Ashley telling me to meet her at a Memorial but she is nowhere to be found

Tags: mass-effect-3

Ashley is not part of Normandy anymore (after the Citadel 2 mission) but I still got an email from her telling me to meet her at the Citadel Memorial for something with her sister.

I got to the two memorial areas I know (at the Normandy Docking Bay and the Refugee camps) and Ashley is nowhere to be found.

Did I miss something? Does anyone know where I can find her?

Answer (score 3):

I think you missed it. She should be **on the left upon entering the Docks: Holding Area** (refugee camps), but *only* if you let her back on your team before the Citadel attack.<sup>[1](http://social.bioware.com/forums/forum/Mass-Effect-3/Mass-Effect-3-Character-and-Romance-Discussion/Ashley-not-at-memorial-didn039t-offer-to-join-after-Citadel-invasion-bug-10967738-1.html)</sup> It'll trigger this cutscene if she's there:

Comment: She isn't there unfortunately and that's my issue. Do I have to do something other than read the email to get her there?

Comment: If you didn't let her back aboard the Normandy before the Citadel attack, I don't believe she'll show in the camp (updated answer). The email, then, is most likely a bug. You'll have to reload a hard save and get her to come aboard if you want to continue this arc.

Answer (score 0):

she shows up before you leave to go on the normandy.

Comment: Are you talking about recruiting her into your squad or visiting the memorial with her?